# Is it possible to use multiple Google Map Account under same Application?

Tags: google-maps

I have a Web Application, which is hosted under a domain (say www.xx.com) and I have activated Google Map Account (say, MyAccount) for that Application as well. The Google Map Key under MyAccount; I have enabled for JavaScript Map API and Geocoding API only. There is another option in that Application, which uses Places API, which I haven't enabled due to the heavy costing for that what google have. But, one of my client want to use the Places API option and they have suggested me that to use Client Google Map Account (say, ClientAccount) for that particular Option; where I'll use their Map Key (under ClientAccount) while they sign-in into the Application.  So, the following questions became relevant;

-Is it possible to use Dynamic Map Key under one Project?

- Is there any violation of Terms? if yes, 
           - What is the alternative I can suggest to the client to achieve this requirement?

NB: I cannot make another instance of the application to host for the client as my services are under SaaS model.

Thanks, 
Shenulal

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a project in which you use JavaScript API and Geocoding API. This project is presumably attached to your billing account. Now you have a client that wishes to use Places API, in their own project, with their own API key. And you are asking whether you are allowed to create that new project for them, and link it to your own billing account (or theirs?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this should be possible, just send the customer's key with your Places API requests, and make sure they whitelist your domain in their key restrictions.